# How to remove a repository from Launchpad?

Tags: bazaar, launchpad

Specifically I have a repository setup in Launchpad. I need to remove this repository but didn't find any link to do that from launchpad website. I am wondering whether I could do it on my local branch using "bzr". Or I am missing something from the launchpad website to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have your entire project deleted from Launchpad, you have to post a "question" on this page:

https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+addquestion

Yeah it's weird. But this seems to be the official way. If you search for the keywords "delete project" on this page you will find many many similar requests:
https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad

Make sure to include a detailed explanation why you want to do this and that you are aware of the consequences. Otherwise you will get a response along the lines "the community might still use the source code you want to delete" and so on.

Of course they are right, and you *should* carefully consider whether you really want to remove code that other folks might be using and linking to.

If you are sure you want the project gone, then you can reduce the turnaround time with the Launchpad team by first deleting all your branches. You might not be able to delete the trunk, in that case you can try to force-overwrite it with an empty branch, using these steps:

```
bzr init empty
cd empty
touch empty.txt
bzr add
bzr commit -m 'dummy commit'
bzr push lp:PROJECT --overwrite
```

Of course, replace `PROJECT` with the name of your project. All these steps are necessary to empty the branch. You cannot simply push an empty branch, Bazaar will tell you that `No new revisions or tags to push.` and the branch will be untouched. You need a completely new revision, like the dummy revision in this example.

If your project has no meaningful source code in it, the Launchpad team should not have any objections to delete it, so you can reduce the turnaround time.